# Вывод компонента по нажатию на слово в TextField?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Проблема такая, есть задача выводить компонент(выпадающий список) по нажатию на слово в поле Input. В поле вводиться будет предложение, а затем пользователь нажимает на определенное слово в нем и должен открываться выпадающий список.

Для стилей использую библиотеку Material UI.

Код компонента выглядит так:

```
class Content2 extends React.Component {

constructor(props){
    super(props);
    // initial state
    this.state = {
        textInput: ''
    }
}

clear = () => {
    // return the state to initial
    this.setState({
        textInput: ''
    })
}

render(){
    return (
        <Paper style={{maxWidth: 936, marginLeft: '250px', overflow: 'hidden'}}>
            <AppBar position="static" color="default" elevation={0}>
                <Toolbar>
                    <Grid container spacing={16} alignItems="center">
                        <Grid item xs>
                            <TextField
                                fullWidth
                                placeholder="Введите фразу которую нужно обучить"
                                id = 'textInput'
                                InputProps={{
                                    disableUnderline: true,
                                }}
                                value={this.state.textInput}
                                onChange={(e)=>{this.setState({textInput: e.target.value})}}
                            />
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item>
                            <Button variant="contained" color="primary" style={{background: 'linear-gradient(45deg, #00ACD3 30%, #00BE68 90%)'}}>
                                Обучить
                            </Button>
                            <Tooltip title="Сбросить">
                                <IconButton>
                                    <RefreshIcon color="inherit" style={{display: 'block'}} id = 'clearButton' onClick={this.clear}/>
                                </IconButton>
                            </Tooltip>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </Toolbar>
            </AppBar>
            <div style={{margin: '40px 16px'}}>
                <Typography color="textSecondary" align="center">
                    Пока ничего не было обучено
                </Typography>
            </div>
        </Paper>
    );
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Я не понял, какой список и где нужно показать, но единственный способ отследить нажатие на слово в текстовом поле, который приходит в голову - это проверить, содержится ли нужное слово в поле и совпадает ли позиция курсора в поле с позициями слова, если оно есть в строке.

```js
const WORD = 'слово2';
const input = document.querySelector('input');

input.addEventListener('click', (evt) => {
  // получаем позицию курсора
  const startPosition = evt.target.selectionStart;
  
  // получем позиции первого и последнего симоволов нужного слова
  const wordStartIndex = evt.target.value.indexOf(WORD);
  const wordEndIndex = wordStartIndex + WORD.length;
  
  // если слово содержится в строке и позиция курсора находится между
  // первым и последним его символлами, то выполняем действие
  if(wordStartIndex !== -1 && startPosition >= wordStartIndex && startPosition <= wordEndIndex){
    console.log('нажали на слово');
  }
  
});
```

```html
<input type="text" value="слово1 слово2 слово3" />
```

в случае с реактом это может выглядеть как-то так

```js
class App extends React.Component {

constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        textInput: '',
        clickOnWord: false
    }
}

onWordClick = (e) => {
  const WORD = 'слово';
  const startPosition = e.target.selectionStart;
  
  const wordStartIndex = e.target.value.indexOf(WORD);
  const wordEndIndex = wordStartIndex + WORD.length;
  
  if(wordStartIndex !== -1 && startPosition >= wordStartIndex && startPosition <= wordEndIndex){
    this.setState({clickOnWord: true})
  }else{
    this.setState({clickOnWord: false})
  }
}

render(){
  const clickOnWord = this.state.clickOnWord ? 'нажали на слово' : '';
  return (
  <div>
    <input 
      placeholder="Введите фразу которую нужно обучить"
      type='text'
      id='textInput'
      value={this.state.textInput}
      onChange={(e)=>{this.setState({textInput: e.target.value})}}
      onClick={(e) => this.onWordClick(e) }
    />
    <div>{clickOnWord}</div>
  </div>
  );
}

}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@material-ui/core/umd/material-ui.production.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: в выпадающем списке должны быть синонимы слова, которые я получаю на сервере, он должен появляться примерно под словом, такой способ, который вы предложили не очень подходит, поскольку я заранее не могу знать какое слово введет пользователь